# Bind simple List<t> to DataGrid showing empty values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple single column List that I need to bind to a data grid.  My code loops through a list selected items in a checkbox list and then is supposed to add the selected items to the datagrid.

The problem is that the datagrid creates the appropriate number of rows for the number of items selected, but the values in the grid are all empty.  What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
        //Loop through checkBoxList and add selected items to "selected" 
        List<String> selected = new List<String>();
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxAudienceList.Items)
            if (item.Selected) 
                selected.Add(item.Text);

        //Now bind List<String> to the gridview
        audienceList.DataSource = selected;
        audienceList.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `AutoGenerateColumns` property on your GridView to `true`.

```
<asp:GridView id="audienceList" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ...
```